# Identifying boundaries and objects in real time (tango)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

Is there a possibility with a google tango camera to create a situation, that my player goes on the table and if he comes out of the table he falls? Has anyone ever done anything similar and has references or ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

in order to implement the functionality that you described, you will need to find different planes from the real world and translate their position into Unity scene. There is a class in Tango SDK, called TangoPointCloud which contains several methods for recognizing planes and translate their position into unity scene points. By knowing the positions of the table and the floor, you might be able to implement the feature you want. In my case, TangoPointCloud helped me find the walls from a room and their position relative to unity scene units.

Comment: I thought that was what I would have to do,
Thank you very much.